# Google analytics content grouping setting

Tags: regex, google-analytics

I'm using the regular expressions to identify the page grouping in GA. My current URLs are

```
/product/aaa/summary
/product/bbb/summary
/product/aaa/details
/product/bbb/details
/product/aaa/profile
/product/bbb/profile
```

I want to see the pageviews group by 'summary', 'details', 'profile' instead of different products.

In GA content grouping settings, I'm using `GROUP USING EXTRACTION`. I have the following rules:

```
/product/(.*)/summary
/product/(.*)/details
/product/(.*)/profile
```

In GA All pages, select the content grouping, I got `not set`. I think the way I'm grouping is wrong. How to create grouping by 'summary', 'details', 'profile' instead of different products? Something like `select * from products group by view` in SQL.

Comment: Have you tried with GROUP USING RULE DEFINITIONS -> Page -> matches regex?

Comment: @MichelePisani Thanks for your suggestion. I just tried using rule definitions. I got result like aaa/summary, ccc/summary, bbb/profile.
I'd like to group the result by summary, details, and profile instead of the product.

Comment: Something like this, i.e. for summary? (.*\/summary).*